# Listing Category 'child_of' by slug rather than ID

Tags: categories, page-template

I want to list categories belonging to a parent. The problem is using category id's isn't useful and makes things harder to understand.

Is there any easier way to list categories belonging to a parent, similar to the default way supplied in the WP codec?

```
<?php wp_list_categories('child_of=8'); ?> //what category is '8' ?!

<?php wp_list_categories('child_of=clients'); ?> //much nicer, but doesn't work
```

I would prefer to avoid using another query in the loop, but to make sense to other developers, I might have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get ID from slug quite easily:

```
$category = get_category_by_slug( 'clients' );
wp_list_categories('child_of='.$category->term_id);
```

Comment: I nearly suggested similar using `get_term_by`.. `get_cat_ID` is just easier to use because there's no need to reference object properties. +1 from me though, still a valuable answer!.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want all children on a set category then, as that's essentially what the `child_of` parameter is for, getting all descendants of a term(category).

If you want only terms that have a particular direct parent then you should instead be using `parent`.

In regard to using an ID, this should work..

```
<?php
// Get ID for the named category
$cat_term_id = get_cat_ID( 'my-cat' );

wp_list_categories("parent=$cat_term_id");
//wp_list_categories("child_of=$cat_term_id");
?>
```

---

[get_cat_ID](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID) docs.

---

Hope that helps..

Comment: **NOTE:** `get_cat_ID` also expects the slug, and not the name, like with `get_category_by_slug` .. (however this will give you just the ID, and not an object).

Comment: ehm, I thing your note is backwards :) `get_cat_ID()` expects name, `get_category_by_slug()` expects slug.

Comment: @Rarst - Apologies, my mistake, it does indeed expect the name(i just had this memory in my head about a category function that is documented to expect a name, but actually expects the slug - i got my wires crossed).. ;)

Comment: I too remember some function being like that, but it is neither of these two... yay for having too many functions :)